# Checking the formulas given for the roots of a quartic equation using WolframAlpha

Tags: polynomials, quartics

I know that there is a quartic formula, $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$, and just tried to plug it int 
 into WolframAlpha. It gave me [this huge formula](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ax%5E4%2Bbx%5E3%2Bcx%5E2%2Bdx%2Be) for each root. Is there any way to test if it's actually right, without doing it by hand? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just do the same with $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ an enjoy the formula !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the derivation of the formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots)

Comment: I'm not interested in the derivation, I'm interested to know if the formula on WolframAlpha actually works.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, it's really hard to read. The best way to decide that is to try it for for a few equations and see what happens

Comment: @AaronM The derivation shows the pieces that are assembled into those huge formulas. You can use the derivation to find those pieces and subassemblies of pieces in the Wolfram Alpha formulas and check that the ones that should exist are there. Or you can open the image shown in the thumbnail over the caption "Quartic formula written out in full," and see if those equations match Wolfram Alpha's. Either way you may have to do some algebra as there are multiple ways to write the same thing, e.g. $\frac1x-\frac1y$ vs. $\frac{y-x}{xy}$. Or try it on a few quartic equations, as suggested.